# How we can specify mapping files using <mapping file=""/> in hibernate configuration file

Tags: hibernate

I have hibernate configuration file as follows

```
    en<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mining</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping file="WEB-INF/mams-hibern.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But I get exception

```
org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: file: WEB-INF\mams-hibern.xml not found
```

The cfg file is located in

```
project>src>hiber.cfg.xml
```

And mams-hibern.xml containg mapping is located in folder

```
project>WebContent>WEB-INF>mams-hibern.xml
```

What is the solution for this.Any one know please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ID like **eclipse** put your hbm File in  `project>src>mams-hibern.xml`
and in **cfg** file just use

```
<mapping resource="mams-hibern.xml"/>
```

Comment: Above exception is cleared sir.But when executing query I get   an exception org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Applicant is not mapped [select a from Applicant as a inner join a.applications as b inner join b.applicationType as c inner join b.permits as d where d.permitNo=? and c.applicationTypeId=?].Here Applicant mapping file is included in mams-hibern.xml

Comment: Do not put your question in comment . put it On question and let me know